# Dataflow job doesn't consume from PubSub when launched from template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I currently have a job which outputs the contents of a pubsub topic to a cloud storage folder which works fine if I launch the jar directly.

However, whenever I try to launch the job using the template I uploaded, no messages go through the pipeline.

It's very similar to [the Google provided template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtogcstext) except it accepts a subscription instead of a topic.

Here's my configuration:

```
trait Options extends PipelineOptions with StreamingOptions {
  @Description("The Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to read from")
  @Default.String("projects/project/subscriptions/subscription")
  def getInputSubscription: String
  def setInputSubscription(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The Cloud Storage directory to output files to, ends with /")
  @Default.String("gs://tmp/")
  def getOutputDirectory: String
  def setOutputDirectory(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The Cloud Storage prefix to output files to")
  @Default.String("subscription-")
  def getOutputFilenamePrefix: String
  def setOutputFilenamePrefix(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The shard template which will be part of the filenames")
  @Default.String("-W-P-SSSSS-of-NNNNN")
  def getShardTemplate: String
  def setShardTemplate(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The suffix of the filenames written out")
  @Default.String(".txt")
  def getOutputFilenameSuffix: String
  def setOutputFilenameSuffix(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The window duration in minutes, defaults to 5")
  @Default.Integer(5)
  def getWindowDuration: Int
  def setWindowDuration(value: Int): Unit

  @Description("The compression used (gzip, bz2 or none), bz2 can't be loaded into BigQuery")
  @Default.String("none")
  def getCompression: String
  def setCompression(value: String): Unit

  @Description("The maximum number of output shards produced when writing")
  @Default.Integer(1)
  def getNumShards: Int
  def setNumShards(value: Int): Unit
}
```

and here's how I launch the template:

```
   gcloud dataflow jobs run storage \
     --gcs-location gs://bucket/templates/Storage \
     --parameters runner=DataflowRunner,project=project,streaming=true,inputSubscription=projects/project/subscriptions/sub,outputDirectory=gs://bucket/
```

Here's how I launch the job without the template:

```
./storage \
  --runner=DataFlowRunner \
  --project=project \
  --streaming=true \
  --gcpTempLocation=gs://tmp-bucket/ \
  --inputSubscription=projects/project/subscriptions/sub  \
  --outputDirectory=gs://bucket/
```

Comment: Have you tried changing to `inputSubscription=sub` instead of `inputSubscription=projects/project/subscriptions/sub`?

Comment: I suspect that this can be because, for template options to be resolved at runtime, you need to use ValueProviders ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates)). Using the Console [UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow) you can select a specific job and find the pipeline options in the right-side bar. Is `inputSubscription` correctly populated for the templated job?

Comment: Yes unfortunately the options are correctly populated in the right-side bar. All the defaults are being correctly overwritten. Unfortunately I'd like to avoid `ValueProvider` because they're not supported in [Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/696).

Comment: Although you might very well be onto something as when I hover over the params in the console for the working job I get my full package (e.g. `com.package.Options.inputSubscription`) whereas when I hover over the params for the job not working I only get the param name (e.g. `inputSubscription`).

Comment: You were right, `ValueProvider`s are mandatory for the template to work.

Comment: Hi @BenFradet , did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, basically everything needs to be a `ValueProvider`

Comment: @BenFradet glad to hear! I will put a community wiki answer so other users with the same issue can find the solution easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GuillemXercavins comment stated, the parameters have to use [the `ValueProvider` interface as their type](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates). This will allow the pipeline options to be set or used at runtime, which is what caused the issue.

It's worth pointing out, as you already did in a comment, that `ValueProvider` seems to be [unsupported in Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/696).

---

**Edit:**

[Scio example](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/TemplateExample.scala) provided by [@BenFradet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2186900/benfradet) in comment below.

Comment: I wrote an example in scio for future reference: https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/TemplateExample.scala